# Cambiar de un textField a otro TextField al darle a continuar en el teclado de IOS

Tags: swift2, swift, swift3

Como puedo pasar de un `textfield` a otro `textfield` al darle al botón continuar del teclado de `ios`??

He probado con un `@IBAction` pero solo me funciona si cambio manualmente de `textfield`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible hacerlo de forma automática. La mejor forma es implementar el siguiente método delegado:

```
textFieldShouldReturn(_:)
```

En él, detectar qué `textField` es el actual, y hacer que el siguiente `textField` pase a ser el activo con:

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Si necesitas saber el orden y en cuál estás en ese momento, utiliza el método delegado `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)` y asígnale un `tag` de orden a cada `textField` de manera que si estás en el `tag` 3 el siguiente sea el 4

Comment: Pero como se cuando clicko uno u otro?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta